# How to setup multi store in localhost for nopcommerce 4.0? (.net core)

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, multistore, nopcommerce-4.0

I setup nopcommerce in IIS after publish Nop.Web project.

I set different domains in hosts file as below,

```
127.0.0.1   www.store1.local
127.0.0.1   www.store2.local
```

In IIS, I bind www.store1.local with publish folder, It is working fine with www.store1.local.

But how can I setup multistore with using www.store2.local and other custom URLs, Can anyone please guide me for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Visit to Store configuration under Admin > Configuration > Stores

Add here one by one two stores with store name and proper store URL
1. www.store1.local
2. www.store2.local

Now you have to configure Host values of store
Set Host values `store1.local, www.store1.local` for store 1
and `store2.local, www.store2.local` for store 2.

Now restart store from admin panel and this will work.

On IIS End,
You can edit bind setting and add new binding for store 2 - www.store2.local on same site.

Make sure **your Host file is updated with both domain name** as mentioned in your descriptio if you host on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add two bindings www.store1.local, www.store2.local to the same folder and add the host variables to the to stores in the admin panel.